# iframe in Mixed content on https

Tags: php, ssl, https

i have a domain name hosted on https and on a page I am using a  with an external tool, that is not under https

the problem is that it is not loaded as it is under http

Is there a way to solve this? any idea?

Answer (score -1):

Use without http and https. ie) url like //www.domain.com

Comment: That would still require that tool to support SSL, which it doesn't. A scheme-relative URL will still use `https:` if the base URL uses `https:`.

Comment: with that it will only take https or http depending on what is available. so it will not solve my problem